# Post date value over REST API to mongoDB and store it as ISOdate

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, flask, isodate

I have a working server that receives data from client machine and stores it into mongoDB. It looks something like

```
while True:
    data = { "timestamp": datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat(),
             "value": get_value(),
           }
    response, content = http.request(url,'POST', json.dumps(data),headers=headers)
    time.sleep(5)
```

data is sent to the server every 5 seconds. My problem is that the `timestamp` value is stored as a string and not as ISOdate. How can I store it as ISOdate? or more precisely, how can I change the `timestamp` value to ISOdate?

Edit: I found a way to convert the values to date in mongo console, but I need to have this done automatically for every new entry.

Comment: What is the server software that is listening at the `url` location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this?

```
import datetime

****
timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
isoDate = datetime.datetime.strptime( timestamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f" )
print (timestamp)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but this doesn't solve my problem as the date is not JSON serializable when sent over the POST request. I think the timestamp field should be ISOdate after it is sent to the server.